How to validate a ceritifcate chain in mTLS using nginx ingress controller in kubernetes
I'm implementing mutual TLS through my nginx ingress controller in kubernetes,
and I was able to implement a basic one, using a self signed certificate (OpenSSL) acting as the root certificate,
and requests now need to have a certificate signed by the certificate in the controller
using this annotation in the controller:
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: default/ca-secret
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "1"

Where default/ca-secret is the root certificate
I want this mTLS to be through a certificate chain, where all of the chains verified at once with each request.
So I want the client to have a certificate signed by C, and C is originally signed by B and B is originally signed by A and A is originally signed by the root certificate.
How do I achieve this using nginx ingress controller, where the request doesn't only verify using C, but using the entire chain.
I implemented one root certificate and one client certificate

Your desire to have is about Root CA, intermediate and leaf cert I think. What's your certificate authority(CA) such cert-manager or Let's encrypt?
Also, how do you use either Issuer or ClusterIsuser?
